# relative path to consume local asmx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, asmx

In my asp.net webapp I'm using a local webservice to retrieve data's. The system is in a popup (wich is an another page in fact)
So here's the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlToBind').change(function () {            
        var parameter = "{'aId':'" + $("#ddl").val() + "'}";
        $.ajax({
            url: "../WebServicesASMX/PMywebserv.asmx/Test",
            data: parameter,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ddlToBind>option').remove();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                    $("#ddlToBind").append("<option value='" + data.d[i].Id + "'>" + data.d[i].Name + "</option>");
                };                                       
            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

It is working good while you are in the root of site and once you launch the script in other pages the path is not correct so asmx is not reached..

I've tried with the tilde "~" in place of ../ but it doesn't work.. `url: "~/WebServicesASMX/PMywebserv.asmx/Test"`

Is it a possibility to specify relatives path in my jquery script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualPathUtility to the rescue!

```
url: "<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/WebServicesASMX/PMywebserv.asmx/Test") %>",
```

See this post by Rick Strahl: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths

Note that for this to work the script needs to be in a page that is processed by ASP.NET e.g. aspx, ascx, MVC View. If your script is in a plain js file, you'll need to move it, or reference a javascript global variable that you define elsewhere in ASP.NET code.

Comment: Thanks choose yours for explanations

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebServicesASMX/PMywebserv.asmx/Test") %>
```